# Praat Script: How to Reverse Selected Sound File?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, praat, spoken-language

I want to reverse a sound file using `Praat`. **I tried to figure out the way to do it and found that there's a shortcut Ctrl+R in the `Edit` menu.** but I want to do the same thing using the script.

Someone please guide me about **how can we reverse a sound file in Praat script ?**

Comment: Do you know that all commands you find in the objects window can be called in a script? And IIRC there should be a 'reverse' command/button somewhere in the objects window.

Comment: I am a beginner and don't know much about `Praat` and I just assumed that there would be a such command as I found [To TextGrid (silences)...](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Sound__To_TextGrid__silences____.html) command in similar way

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Reverse` command, under the "Modify" menu for `Sound` objects.

You could also (although it would be of limited real-world use) write it yourself by accessing the individual samples, as illustrated in the [manual](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Formulas_8__Data_in_objects.html) (under *Object contents in a modification formula*).